# VSTO: Can I set idMso to button with ribbon designer?

Tags: c#, vsto

Can I set idMso attributes to button with the ribbon designer?

I'd like to show built-in buttons in my custom tab in PowerPoint VSTO add-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to deal with Ribbon XML if you need to set the `idMso` property. Note, you can design your custom UI using the ribbon designer and then export it to the ribbon XML file which can be edited later. See [How to: Export a ribbon from the Ribbon Designer to Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-export-a-ribbon-from-the-ribbon-designer-to-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019) for more information.